# Login script, how does TIMEDIFF work?

Tags: php, sql, datetime, time

I'm creating a login script. In this script, I would like to limit the users login attempts, but only for an hour. After an hour, they can try again, several times, before waiting another hour. In my database, I have ID, IP address and DateTime fields.

I have Google'd it, and didn't found a solution. However, from searching on the TIMEDIFF, there was quite a lot information. From that, I've made the query and script below. The problem is, it doesn't work. Could you help me to make it working?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `log` WHERE `ip` = '".$ip."' AND TIMEDIFF('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."',`datetime`) > '24:00:00'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows   = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows >= $this->maxAttempts)
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using simple math and the `INTERVAL` syntax instead:

```
SELECT *
  FROM log
 WHERE ip = ?
   AND (datetime + INTERVAL 1 HOUR) > NOW()
```